# Node.js create function with mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

im currently trying to create an event to and store it in my mongo database. Below is my current event schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//blueprint for each new entry in the db
var eventSchema = new Schema({
    eventName: {type:String},
    eventDate: {type:String},
    eventPlace:{type:String},
    eventPrice: {type: Number}

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

Here is my create function code in my user.js file

```
 // /route for new event
    router.get('/newEvent', function (req,res,next) {
        var messages = req.flash('error');
        res.render('user/newEvent',{csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),messages: messages, hasErrors: messages.length >0});
    });

    //route for new event save
    router.get('/createEvent', function(req, res, next) {

      var event = new Event();
      eventName = req.body.eventName;
      eventDate = req.body.eventDate;
      eventPlace = req.body.eventPlace;
      eventPrice = req.body.eventPrice;

      event.save(function(err) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.json({ message : 'Success!'});
      });
    });
```

And here is my form to create the new event in my newEvent.hbs file.

```
    <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <h1> Create a new Event</h1>
                {{#if hasErrors}}
                    <div class=alert alert-danger">
                        {{# each messages}}
                            <p>{{this}}</p>
                        {{/each}}
                    </div>
                {{/if}}

                <form action="/user/newEvent" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="eventName">Event Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventName" name="eventName"class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="eventDate">Event Date</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventDate" name="eventDate" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="eventPlace">Place of Event</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventPlace" name="eventPlace" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="eventPrice">Price of Event: €</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventPrice" name="eventPrice" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken}}">
               <a href="createEvent" class="pull-right btn btn-success" role="button">Create Event</a>
            </form>
    </div>
```

So far when i run the code I get an error stating that the eventName, eventPlace, eventDate and eventPrice are required and havent been entered but when i remove the "required:true" from the events schema a new event is created but no data is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

1- You are not saving the events correctly `eventName = req.body.eventName`

currently you are saving empty object, thats why when you remove required it save empty data.

2- You are also using `req.body` with get request you should be using `router.post`

Check the code below

```
router.post('/createEvent', function(req, res, next) {

  var event = new Event({
    eventName:req.body.eventName,
    eventDate : req.body.eventDate,
    eventPlace : req.body.eventPlace,
    eventPrice : req.body.eventPrice
  });

  event.save(function(err) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json({ message : 'Success!'});
  });
});
```

Comment: so i have tried that code and im still getting the error of vent validation failed.

Comment: i edited the code please try using this one i passed the object in Event initialization this should work

Comment: So now the error is gone when I create the event but no data is being stored in to the database

Comment: make sure that req.body contains the correct data ex: ```console.log(req.body)``` and check if the values of ```eventName,eventDate,....etc```  are correct